# "Quote is marked for soft delete and cannot be retrieved"

Tags: quote, undelete

I have un-deleted the quote from Recycle bin. But when I'm trying to access the quote, it's showing as "Quote is marked for soft delete and cannot be retrieved". How do I recover those quotes?